# Convert Number to Unicode sign

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode, numbers, letter

I have to print out the letters from A to Z each for itself. So I tried the following:

```
for(var i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
     $('#alphabet').append('<div class="letter">' + '%' + i + '</div>');
}
```

My idea is to use the decimal numbers of the letters (for example: 65 - A) to easily print them via loop. Is this possible or do I have to use an array?

Best regards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [String.fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) to convert a character code to string.

Comment: thats exactly what i've been looking for (hours). thank you very much!

Comment: @Josh Why write the name of Stefan Surkamp in Russian when he/she appears to be a German? Also "Ш" appears to imitate the pronounciation in Deutsche, quite interesting. :)

Comment: I'm sure I used autocomplete @awllower. I bet he's changed his display name ;-)

Comment: @Josh I found out that there is such a functionality as auto-complete after using the website for 3 years and 11 months (on math stack exchange). Thanks for that information. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For this use (printing letters from A to Z), `String.fromCharCode` is sufficient; however, the question title specifies Unicode. If you are looking to convert Unicode codes (and if you came here from search, you might), you need to use [`String.fromCodePoint`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCodePoint).

Note, this function is new to ES6/ES2015, and you may need to use a transpiler or polyfill to use it in older browsers.